# Line Integral over curve $\gamma$, how would the sign change if the orientation was reversed?

Tags: calculus

I have a line integral over a curve $\gamma$

$$\gamma(t) = \langle1, 1 - t\rangle$$

$$\int_{\gamma(0)}^{\gamma(1)} f(x,y) ds$$

Now, because $\gamma'(t) = \langle0, -1\rangle$, $\lVert \gamma'(t) \rVert = 1$

$$I_\gamma = \int_{0}^1 f(1,1-t) \lVert \gamma'(t) \rVert dt = \int_{0}^1 f(1,1-t) dt $$

Now suppose, that the path was in fact going in the opposite direction, that is $\Gamma = <1, t>$. Following the same logic, I would get to

$$I_\Gamma = \int_{0}^1 f(1,t) dt$$

I believe that $I_\gamma = -I_\Gamma$, is this correct? Although, I do not see how this is the case just by examining $I_\gamma$ and $I_\Gamma$

Comment: After the substitution $u=1-t...$